# Exporting a Java project that uses PostgreSQL

Tags: java, database, postgresql, jdbc

I couldn't find an answer to this question. How can I export a Java project that makes use of a PostgreSQL database?

I want to use the same database on another computer. Do I need to export the database itself with the project? How can this be done?

What should the connection URL be, so that the database is accessible on another computer?

I'm using JDBC, and I'm on Windows.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Wouldn't I also need to dynamically retrieve the username and password on the other computer, instead of using the specific username and password I have on my computer in PostgreSQL?

Comment: Are you trying to export the _project_ (which will require project _and_ database), or just the _database_ ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The entire project.

Comment: What's the "project" at the moment? How was it built, and using what tools? It sounds like you've used something that's been managing your database definition for you so far.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you want to achieve.

### Shared database between hosts

Do you want the application on both computers to use the same database, so that changes made by one are seen on the other? If so, you need to configure each copy of the application to connect to the same database instance on one of the machines. This is usually done by changing the JDBC URL. You'll need to configure PostgreSQL on the machine that'll be the database server so it allows connections from the other hosts, ensure they can talk to each other over TCP/IP, etc.

### Fresh DB on each host

Do you want each install to have a separate instance of the database, so changes made on one have no effect on the other, and where each instance starts out with a blank, empty database (or one with only static contents like lookup tables)? If so, you should generally define the database using SQL scripts, then have the application run the SQL scripts when first installed on a machine. If you've defined the database by hand so far, you can use `pg_dump` to create a SQL script that you can use as the basis for this, but I really advise you to look into tools like Liquibase for schema management instead.

### "Fork" current state

Do you want each instance of the application on a machine to have an independent database, so changes made on one have no effect on other instances on other machines, but where the starting state of an install is what was in the database on the other host? If so, you need to *dump* and *reload* the database alongside the application, using `pg_dump -Fc` and `pg_restore`. You can automate this within your application / build system using tools like `ProcessBuilder`, or do it manually.

There's no generic, canned way to do this. It'll require you to define an application deployment procedure, maybe produce an installer, etc.